# global variable dead in function javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to update a global array with js, and I just realized I cannot access anything about it from anywhere in a function. When the if/else statement is removed, the alert for new_time works, but the last alert doesn't. With the if/else there, it fries my code and nothing runs. I read that you can access global variables just by their name, so why does `changed_select_box_array` cause problems here? (also tried calling it as global., window., and this.)

```
var one = document.optionObject("id_open_time_1");

var changed_select_box_array = [];

function showID(id){
    if (changed_select_box_array.length > 0){
        alert('somethin');
    }
    else{
        alert('nuttin');
    }
    var x = document.getElementById(id).selectedIndex;
    var time = document.getElementsByTagName("option")[x].value;
    var change = {id:id, new_time:time};

    alert(change.new_time);

    changed_select_box_array.push(change);
    alert(changed_select_box_array[0].id);
}
```

Somehow, this snippet from above (which hadn't affected anything for several days) was causing the problem:

```
    var one = document.optionObject("id_open_time_1");
```

I'd love to know why that causes an issue

Comment: What does the last alert shows?

Comment: the only alert that will ever work is `alert(change.new_time);`, showing the time you change to (like 01:30), and only if I delete the entire if/else clause

Comment: Works fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/qkL03a48/ Are you showing us all of the relevant code? Please give us a _reproducible_ example.

Comment: the question is now why did that screw up the rest? I didn't see any relevance it had

Comment: what do you mean console errors? I just started JS a few days ago. Run Javascript console, or developer tools?

Comment: I have no idea what `document.optionObject` is. It sounds like an example code, i.e. _insert your own option object here_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not see an error. Works for me.

```
<select id="test">
    <option value="1">T1</option>
    <option value="2" selected>T2</option>
    <option value="3">T3</option>
</select>

<script>
var changed_select_box_array = [];
showID('test');

function showID(id){
    if (changed_select_box_array.length > 0){
        alert('somethin');
    }
    else{
        alert('nuttin');
    }
    var x = document.getElementById(id).selectedIndex;
    var time = document.getElementsByTagName("option")[x].value;
    var change = {id:id, new_time:time};

    alert(change.new_time);

    changed_select_box_array.push(change);
    alert(changed_select_box_array[0].id);
}
</script>
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zxyuumgf/)

Comment: please see my edit, I'm wondering exactly what optionObject does behind the scenes that blows up the rest of my code (but ONLY when accessing the global array)

Comment: Yet, this working example omits the "document.optionObject" line which the question mentions. And if you add it?

Comment: Unless you have added optionObject to the document (assigning it directly: document.optionObject = function(parameter) {return parameter};) then document object does not have such function and it throws an error when you call it, which stops further execution of your code. Even if you did, its probably a bad idea to add new functions directly to the document object.